# Display menu edition form, try show only part of menu tree

Tags: 7, routes

I'm trying to display in my module editing form of a menu (the one with dragable items, $q=admin/structure/menu/manage/{menu_name}). Function I stumbled upon during research:

```
menu_tree_page_data
drupal_get_form
theme_menu_overview_form (cannot be called, core module function)
```

Ideally I would like to show user only part of the tree and let him edit only this part of the bigger menu. Has anyone of you played with such a thing?

Comment: to answer myself – I think now, that analyzing OG Menu module php files might be some point to start..

Comment: there's something what makes the job done but only for D6: http://drupal.org/project/delegate_menu_admin